# Convert Ctrl-space to non-break-space (for FL&U)

Tags: script

This is a mini-script to convert Ctrl+Space to a non-break-space (0x160, not `&nbsp;`).

You can copy-paste the code below (if you want to change the includes, for example), or check out the gist here:

**UPDATE**, now converts `"` to `«` and `»` (alternately).

Click [HERE](https://gist.github.com/raw/1188013/nonbreakspaces.user.js) to install the user script.

Click [HERE](https://gist.github.com/1188013) to preview the code.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name NonBreakSpaces+
// @namespace benjol
// @description Make Ctrl-space add a non-break-space in textareas
// @include http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @include http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @include http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/*
// ==/UserScript==
function inject(f) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")()";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
};

//Note that if you copy in Firefox, you'll get the impression that the nbsp isn't there, but it is!
// (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=359303)
inject(function () {
  var nbsp = String.fromCharCode(160),
      left = "«" + nbsp, //171
      right = nbsp + "»", //187
      next = left;

  function insert(field, val) {
    if(field.selectionStart || field.selectionStart == '0') {
      var cursorAfter = field.selectionStart + val.length;
      var first = field.value.slice(0, field.selectionStart);
      var second = field.value.slice(field.selectionEnd);
      field.value = first + val + second;
      field.setSelectionRange(cursorAfter, cursorAfter);
    }
    else //won't work in IE, sorry!
      field.value += val;
  }

  $(document).keypress(function(event) {
    var field = event.target;

    if(event.ctrlKey && event.charCode == 32) {
        insert(field, nbsp);
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if (event.charCode == 34) {
        insert(field, next);
next = (next == left) ? right : left;
        event.preventDefault();
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: You should include meta.french.*

Comment: @M'vy, good point, fixed.

Comment: You should use the narrow no-break space ‘U+202F’ after `«` and before `»`. I'm a total js-ignorant, would it be possible to perform automatic substitutions just before submitting content? e.g. "\u020?" → "\u202F?". or "\u020:" → "\u00A0:"?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, Word doesn't seem to like your nnbsp... not sure if that's a deal-breaker or not..

Comment: Word? Anyway, if you know how to hook some substitutions just before the contents submission, I'd be really interested in using it.

Comment: @Stéphane, I'll have a look, it's slightly more complicated because I have to check *which* textarea is being submitted (currently I just replace anything as you type in any textarea).

Comment: @Stéphane, for Word, see the screenshot I pasted in the answer below. It doesn't recognise narrow no break spaces. Not exactly a show-stopper, but it's what makes me hesitate to implement your request.

Answer (score 2):

(Screenshot for Stéphane)

[image: Word no likee]

[image: Nor Windows]

Comment: It's very ugly, it will be better to use non-breaking space instead of narrow non-breaking space !!